# Trying to use Find (Hightlight) in AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer - asp.net.core

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-core

Report Paging works, Refresh works, Export (with some probs) and Print works but Find does not highlight anything.

Find code is:

```
function findText() {
            $('.ReportViewerContent').removeHighlight();
            var searchText = $("#ReportViewerSearchText").val();
            if (searchText != undefined && searchText != null && searchText != "") {
                showLoadingProgress('Searching Report...');
                var params = $('.ParametersContainer :input').serializeArray();
                var urlParams = $.param(params);

                var page = parseInt($('#ReportViewerCurrentPage').val());

                $.get("/Report/FindStringInReport/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&searchText=" + searchText + "&" + urlParams).done(function (data) {
                    if (data > 0) {
                        viewReportPage(data, function () {
                            $('.ReportViewerContent').highlight(searchText);
                            hideLoadingProgress();
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('.ReportViewerContent').highlight(searchText);
                        hideLoadingProgress();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Scripts in _Layout are:

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Scripts in Report Viewer are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/mvcreportviewer-bootstrap.css" />       
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/select2.min.4.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.highlight-5.js"></script>
```

Have tried options like:

```
$('.ReportViewerContent').highlight(searchText, { wholeWord: false, ignoreCase: true, color: "#ffff00", bold: true });
```

Any thoughts please.

Comment: So, no one has it working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested on my working environment and it is highlighting. It does require a css class for it to highlight appropriately. So be sure that you have a ".highlight" style similar to this:

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```